# How can I add term sets through wsp in SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, term-store, office-365-developer

I want to add term sets to my SharePoint site on O365.

How can I add it from visual studio wsp.
Is there a way to do it through declarative xml.

Answer (score 1):

PnP team has created a sample App for this, you can check it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/taxonomy-operations-sample-app-for-sharepoint